# An undefined control sequence is shown

Tags: undefined

An undefined control sequence is shown in the line.

```
\centerline{\LARGE{$\bm{\mathfrak{ Dedicated \ to}}$}}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you look at the error message in the log, there will be a line break somewhere in that piece of code. The undefined command is the one just before that line break.

Comment: Compiles without problems with `\usepackage{amssymb,bm}` for me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Unrelated: `\LARGE` does not take arguments

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your kind response!

Comment: @Henri Menke Yes! Its now working with \usepackage{amssymb,bm}.  Thank you Sir!

Comment: Well, using `\mathfrak` for text is not the best idea, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load `amsfonts` for `\mathfrak` and `bm` for `\bm`, but you can avoid `\bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\usefont{U}{euf}{b}{n}\LARGE
Dedicated to
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: the `\mathfrak` declaration uses the `euf` font family with `U` encoding because of

```
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
    \SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
```

in `amsfonts.sty`.

You can get different styles of Fraktur or similar scripts with `yfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\frakfamily\LARGE
Dedicated to
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\gothfamily\LARGE
Dedicated to
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\swabfamily\LARGE
Dedicated to
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]